# TestCase writing for Django authenticated API View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I have successfully write at TestCase and it's working very fine.

At first have a look at my code:

Below is my `tests.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from ng.models import Contact


class TestNoteApi(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create movie
        self.contact = Contact(userId=254, name="The Space Between Us", phone=2017, email='doe@f.com')
        self.contact.save()

    def test_movie_creation(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('getAndPost'), {
            'userId': 253,
            'name': 'Bee Movie',
            'phone': 2007,
            'email': 'ad@kjfd.com'
        })
        self.assertEqual(Contact.objects.count(), 2)
```

Above snippet working fine but the problem is.. Once i implement authentication system, it not works

below is my `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

if i change into `AllowAny` in permisison, The test works nice but if keep `IsAuthenticated` instead of `AllowAny` , it not works.

I want the test should run nicely even once i keep `IsAuthenticated` in permission.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do it? I am not getting what to change or what add in my `tests.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `user` object in `setUp` method, and use [`client.login()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#loginkwargs) or [`force_authenticate()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#force_authenticateusernone-tokennone) to make authenticated request:

```
class TestNoteApi(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create user
        self.user = User.objects.create(username="test", password="test") 
        # create movie
        self.contact = Contact(userId=254, name="The Space Between Us", phone=2017, email='doe@f.com')
        self.contact.save()

    def test_movie_creation(self):
        # authenticate client before request 
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')
        # or 
        self.clint.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('getAndPost'), {
            'userId': 253,
            'name': 'Bee Movie',
            'phone': 2007,
            'email': 'ad@kjfd.com'
        })
        self.assertEqual(Contact.objects.count(), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have documentation of force_authentication but i couldnt implement. can you help me to do in my code?

Comment: I couldnt implement this, can you help me please?